# Delta dates in Django template

Tags: html, django, django-templates

I have created a view which passes two dates for an item to html template. I get both the dates in the html template as shown below:

```
{% for item in items %}
{{ item.form_date }}
{{ item.to_date }}
      # I need the difference between the dates here....
{% endfor %}
```

I don't want to return the difference data form the view, but want to see delta of the dates here in html. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

you can try [timesince](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#timesince)

```
{{ item.form_date|timesince:item.to_date }}
```

Comment: I have tried but it shows error. I also replaced comment_date with to_date but still the same error is shown

Comment: Thanks. It worked. But it shows `1 week, 1 day`. Can I change the format for days. Can't the output be '8 days' ?

Comment: No there are no any error. I got the output but I want to change the format of the output. Currently it is showing outputs like `1 week, 1 day` or `1 month, 1 week` but I want in days format. Insted of showing `1 week, 1 day` cant it be `8 days`??

Comment: no you can not change the form of output, you can only write you custom tags [example here shippet](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/210/)